# Link crawler (for download or development)

Tags: php, file-io, web-crawler

I have a question regarding webcrawling.. 
What I need is a webcrawler that can save all external links from a website and print them to a file (csv). 
I am in the middle of developing it myself (with php), but was wondering if there were some downloadable solutions already (doesn't have to be php solution)..
Of course I have looked for myself, but couldn't find anything. So if anyone can help me out here, I would really appreciate it.

Also, what would be the best way to developing it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Simple HTML Dom Parser` (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Eg.

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com/');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
 $link[]=$element->href;

}
//Write into your CSV file


?>
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks :) sorry if im asking stupid, but does i search for links in 'child pages' too (all the pages on the website)?

Comment: @user68621 It won't search child pages link. If you provide a URL, it'll search all links exists in that particular URL not the links within any of the child pages from that URL. In order to achieve that, you've to pass links to the function recursively. That'll take alot time if the website is too big cuz that'll have search through all pages/Innerpages so I would recommend this method for Big websites but for small websites with medium links within that!

Comment: okay, I'll give it a shot and go down a couple of levels then. But is it faster to use the DOM Parser than using php's file_get_contents and regex?

Comment: @user68621 file_get_contents and regex will be faster. But I don't think you'll experience those difference much maybe with giant sites You'll see those difference. [One correction in my previous comment : Read as I wouldn't recommend instead I would recommend]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll accept your answer. I ended up doing something else though. I downloaded the "LinkChecker 8.6", which can export to csv. Then I used "sublime text" for sorting the links. Just if anyone else should be seeking something similiar